# How do we find the equation of the plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The exact question is:
b) Give both the rectangular and parametric descriptions of the plane π that passes
through the points $(1, 0, 2),(−3, −1, 4)$ and $(1, 1, 3)$.

(c) Give a parametric description of the line through $(0, 2, 1)$ and orthogonal to π.
Where does this line meet $π$?
For b) I found the parametric description which is:

$$(1,0,2)+t(-4-1,2)+s(0,1,1)$$
Then for the rectanglar description:
$$x=1-4t$$    $$ y=-t+s$$  $$z=2+2t+s$$

Therefore:
$\frac{-x+1}{4}=s-y=\frac{z-2-s}{2}$

However I am confused about the c) part. How do we put the rectangular equation in the form: $ax+by+cz=d$ so we can find the parametric description for the line that is orthogonal to that plane? How do we find coefficients $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 0):

Denote your three points $A, B, C$. A vector  normal to the plane $\Pi$ is the cross-product $\overrightarrow{AB}\times \overrightarrow{AC}$ (or any vector collinear to the cross-product), hence a parametric of the line through $(0,2,1)$, perpendicular to $\Pi$ is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}+t\overrightarrow{AB}\times \overrightarrow{AC}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
(I've  factoredg out $-4$ from the cross-product), and the plane $\Pi$ has equation $x-2y+z=d$, $d$ being determined by writing it passes though $A$, for instance: $1-0+3=d$, so its equation is
$$x-2y+z=3.$$